# Is there any way to get the text data of first non empty element using query selector

Tags: css-selectors, selectors-api

I have just started using `querySelector`. I want to get the text data of first non empty element without concerning the element name (p or div or span).

For example:
1)

```
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span>data</span>
  <span>data1</span>
<div>
```

2)

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>data</li>
  </ul>
  <span>data1</span>
<div>
```

In both the cases I want to get the text data of first element that is non empty. In 1 case from the second `span` and in 2 case from the second `li`. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes)

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because the answers to that question can be used to grab all text nodes, then you'd simply pull only the first one.